# Is it allowed to use nested keys to access Laravel config values?

Tags: laravel, configuration, laravel-5

**myconfig.php**

```
return [
    'key1' => [
        'nested_key1' => 1,
        'nested_key2' => 2
    ],

    'key2' => [
        'nested_key1' => 1,
        'nested_key2' => 2
    ]
];
```

So I have a custom configuration in my `config` directory. Is it possible to set values like this: `config(['myconfig.key1.nested_key1' => 3])`? I can read values this way, but it seems that it's not working when setting new values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do this and it's definitely working:

```
config(['myconfig.key1.nested_key1' => 3]);

echo config('myconfig.key1.nested_key1'); // Will output 3.
```

Values will be saved during current request only. If you want to save data for next requests, you should use a package like [`Laravel Config Writer`](https://github.com/daftspunk/laravel-config-writer) or similar one.

Comment: So to change the value in the file I need to use third party solutions?

Comment: @AndrewVershinin if you want tot save the value for next requests, yes, you should use a package like [`Laravel Config Writer`](https://github.com/daftspunk/laravel-config-writer)